# Installing non-standard fonts

Tags: css

I've followed instructions online to install non-standard fonts, uploading the font.ttf file to my server and adding this to the styles.css in my child theme:

`@font-face {
    font-family: UtopiaStd;
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/opti-child/UtopiaStd-Regular.otf');
}`

However changing the fonts in the theme's styles.css to the new font family does nothing, it just defaults back to the default font for the system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your font is free convert it http://onlinefontconverter.com.

open type can be used in website try appending `format("opentype")`. I will strongly suggest converting this from from given link, if your font is free and open source.

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: UtopiaStd; src: url('/wp-content/themes/opti-child/UtopiaStd-Regular.otf') format("opentype"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however it still defaults to the next font in the family which is Georgia, not the Utopia I want it to use.